# Jquery get the id of clicked link and post it with form data

Tags: jquery

I have two links in a html page. When user clicks one of these links I'd like to get the id of the link and submit it with form data.

My html page is like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var selectedForm = 0;

 window.onload = function() {

     $(".respondButton").on('click', function(e) {
         var selectedButton = $(this).attr('id');
         selectedForm = selectedButton.replace('response', '');
         console.log(selectedForm);
     });

     document.getElementById("submitButton1").onclick = function() {
         doWork()
     };

 }

 function doWork() {

     var response = $('#reply1').val();
     console.log(response);
     $.post({url: "receiver", data: JSON.stringify({selectedForm: selectedForm, response : response}),
             contentType: "application/json", success: function(){}});
     event.preventDefault();
 }

</script>

This will send data using AJAX to Python:<br /><br />

<a id="response1" href="" class="respondButton">
    <span>response1</span>
</a>

<a id="response2" href="" class="respondButton">
    <span>response2</span>
</a>

<form  action="/receiver" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
    <textarea type="text"  rows ="3" name="reply1" id="reply1"></textarea>
    <button type="submit"  name="submitButton1" id="submitButton1">Gönder</button>

</form>
```

When I click one of the links, enter some form data and click submit button selectedForm is always 0.

How can I get the id of the clicked link and submit with form data.

**Update:**

After using $(document).ready(function() { }); rather than window.onload it now works as expected.

[image: Jquery get the id of the clicked link and post it with form data]

Comment: It's working fine for me, I get `1` clicking on response1 and `2` clicking on response2. You're also going to want to prevent the default behavior on these links(`e.preventDefault()`) within the click handler. I'd also use `$(document).ready(function() { });` rather than `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was working for me as is, but I would suggest some changes to clean things up and make it run better:

```js
$(function() {

  var selectedForm = 0;
  
  function doWork() {
    var response = $('#reply1').val();
    console.log(response);
    $.post({url: "receiver", data: JSON.stringify({selectedForm: selectedForm, response : response}),
    contentType: "application/json", success: function(){}});
  }

  $('.respondButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedButton = $(this).attr('id');
    selectedForm = selectedButton.replace('response', '');
    console.log(selectedForm);
  });

  $('#submitButton1').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doWork();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="response1" href="" class="respondButton">
  <span>response1</span>
</a>

<a id="response2" href="" class="respondButton">
  <span>response2</span>
</a>

<form  action="/receiver" method="post" id="form1" name="form1">
  <textarea type="text"  rows ="3" name="reply1" id="reply1"></textarea>
  <button type="submit"  name="submitButton1" id="submitButton1">Gönder</button>
</form>
```